# Angular Modules script not building?

Tags: upgrade, angular, modules

**Background**: Successfully managed to upgrade an old CiviCRM (on WordPress) installation to the latest version a month or so ago (5.48.1) -

**Problem**: I'm still left with this one weird glitch after latest update (to 5.50.3), the console shows file not found at: `/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn/angular.{32-digit-hash}.js`
Clicking on "Rebuild the CiviCRM database triggers" seems to have changed the hash but the file is still not there.

**Workaround**: Renaming an old file from backup to have the same hash in the requested filename fixes the issue.

**Question** My understanding is that a new Angular modules compiled javascript should be built to this location automatically from source? And if that fails it could cause a conflict in the future by using the old compiled modules file? (I checked the directory is writeable and file/user permissions seem to be fine there.)

**Additional**: Also notice there used to be a `angular.{32-digit-hash).json` JSON data file there as well but it doesn't seem to be there now either. Though not causing any visible error (that I know of!) I wonder if these two are supposed to be written together? And what error this could cause if it's missing.

Also have no idea where these hashes are stored, would really like to future proof this installation so it's not facing the same issue with every upgrade.